# Minimize and protect function names inside objects or in the global scope

Tags: javascript, yui, google-closure-compiler

I have tried to minimize my javascript files using YUI compressor, but to no end, I cannot get the names of functions inside objects to minimize. I have tried to minimize function names in the global scope, but have come to understand this is not possible. Is there any way to minimize javascript code in a way that renames the function names also? Perhaps by encapsulating them in an object somehow? Other than obfuscating, which I have read has quality implications, I cannot think of any other way to protect client side code. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure-compiler does this when you use ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS. Be warned however, that it does it to everything unless you take specific steps to prevent this. Converting a large code base to be compatible with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS can be daunting.

See [Which Compilation Level is Right for Me?](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html)

If you are writing a library that others will consume, there are [even more considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495530/1211524).

Comment: Yeah I just ran it with advanced optimizations and the whole application failed. Hmmm...

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle That's pretty normal. Usually code takes modification to be compatible. You'll want to use `--warning_level VERBOSE` and take care of all of the errors and warnings first.